# Sencha Exporting a chart can that be done?

Tags: extjs

In sencha (http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) I was wondering is it possible if i can have a bar chart, or a pie chart and have the data exported? I would like to go back from a chart to a printed data in my hand.

** if i have a bar chart that has data already plotted on it and now i would like to get the x-axis in one column and have the y-axis in another column but i would like to have that exported so i can printed it out. I do not want the chart to be printed.

My question is: Is there a way to do that? and if so what is the code that is needed or used?

CAN I ALSO DO IT IN ZINGCHARTS.COM

what about zingcharts?? i have done my research and found that they have this code called zingchart.exec("yourChartId", "exportdata"); i just dont know how exactly to put it in my zingcharts.rendering function can i get help on that?

Answer (score 2):

I see that this is an older question, but hopefully this will help you or someone else with a similar issue.

The ZingChart exportdata method doesn't actually go in the zingchart.render method, it's its own API method.

```
zingchart.exec('myChartDiv', 'exportdata', {
    url : 'www.zingchart.com/resources/exportdataurl.php'
});
```

'myChartDiv' refers to the id given to the div in your page where your chart renders. You can either set the 'url' option in the export data method options, like I did above or you can set the 'exportdataurl'. The data is sent as POST data via HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get the data? Sure.

Charts are populated by a `store` object, which is a container with all the data.

To get the data out of the store is pretty forward.

Eg:

`store.each(function(store,record,e){console.log(record);});`

Comment: thank you so much for your help is there a way to take it and put it into an excel file?

Comment: You should rather accept an answer for this question, and than ask that as a new question

Comment: what about zingcharts?? i have done my research and found that they have this code called zingchart.exec("yourChartId", "exportdata"); i just dont know how exactly to put it in my zingcharts.rendering function can i get help on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [Export store to Excel user extension](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136598-Export-store-to-Excel) published on Sencha forum.

Comment: what about zingcharts?? i have done my research and found that they have this code called zingchart.exec("yourChartId", "exportdata"); i just dont know how exactly to put it in my zingcharts.rendering function can i get help on that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't had any experience with ZingChart so far, although it does look cool.